# Stored procedure not null and not empty or space

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I try to use stored procedure in my project.However i have question about null and empty.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EMAIL_LIST]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE
EMAIL_ADRESS IS NOT NULL       
END
```

I used where clause for avoid getting values null or empty values however i still get null values.

How can i get email adress values if not null and not empty ?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Side note (if this is for **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
 SELECT 
     *
 FROM 
     CUSTOMER
 WHERE
     EMAIL_ADRESS IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL_ADRESS != ''
```

Keep in mind there is a difference between NULL and ''. '' is simply an empty string. NULL generally is used to indicate an unknown or unspecified value.

Comment: Also you can use a shortned version WHERE EMAIL_ADRESS != '' that is enough to check NULL and empty string http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c3e5/1